# Creating a table in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i want to create SQLite database and table.this is my code please tell me where is my mistake in this code

```
/**
 * Created by Parsian computer on 12/9/2017.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final Integer COL_ID = 0;
    public static final String COL_FirstName = "FirstName";
    public static final String COL_LastName = "LastName";
    public static final String COL_AccountName = "AccountName";
    public static final String COL_Password = "Password";
    public static final String COL_RePassword = "RePassword";
    public static final String Table_Name = "BaharTables";
    private static final String DatabaseName = "BaharDatabase.db";
    public static final String COL_ProductName = "ProductName";
    public static final String COL_ProductPrice = "ProductPrice";
    public static final String COL_IMAGE = "Images";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DatabaseName, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String Table_Create="CREATE TABLE "+Table_Name+
                " ("+COL_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+
                COL_FirstName+" Text,"+
                COL_LastName+" Text,"+
                COL_AccountName+" Text,"+
                COL_Password+" Text,"+
                COL_RePassword+" Text,"+
                COL_ProductName+" Text,"+
                COL_ProductPrice+" Text,"+
                COL_IMAGE+" Blob )";
        db.execSQL(Table_Create);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
db.execSQL("Drop Table if exists "+Table_Name);
onCreate(db);
    }
```

In android-studio doesn't show any error, but the table doesn't create

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid SQLiteOpenHelper. It's given me more problems than it solved. Just create your own system, it isn't harder (IMO, it's easier) than using SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: please send me IMO link.when I search it I find IMO manager

Comment: `IMO` means `In my opinion`

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the error message when the app crashes (which you mentioned below)

Comment: By the way, it's highly recommended not to use raw sqlite anymore. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have column names starting with a numeric (*unless quoted e.g '0', "0", [0] or `0`*).

You have :-

```
..... ("+COL_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ .....
```

COL_ID is defined as 0 (i.e. `private static final Integer COL_ID = 0;`)

So the above equates to `....(0 integer primary key autoincrement, ......`

You could try changing :-

```
    private static final Integer COL_ID = 0;
```

to :-

```
    public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
```

After making the above change you should then do one of the following before rerunning the App :-

- Delete the App's Data.
- Uninstall the App.
- change `super(context, DatabaseName, null, 1)` to `super(context, DatabaseName, null, 2)`

The need to do one of the above is because the `onCreate` method will only automatically run once when the database is created. The first two options will delete the database. The third option will result in the `onUpgrade` method running which then calls the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Could also use `BaseColumns.ID`

Answer (score 0):

The onCreate method will only be called if you try to access the database from any other part of your app. Just call getReadableDatabase() and the db will be created.

Comment: I called it in another activity but it doesn't work. when I call getReadableDatabase() in my main activity my app went crash. i called like this  .  DatabaseHelper databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: And what is the stacktrace?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean sir. I'm a beginner in android

Comment: The stacktrace is the trace of the exception produced when your app crash. Just reproduce the error again and post here what the logcat window shows.
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces.html